# Using SWIG to wrap c++ to java UnsatisfiedLinkError: HeaderJNI.new_Test()J

Tags: java, c++, swig, unsatisfiedlinkerror

I have been trying to use SWIG in my project. It seems that I am missing something. Please help. What I have done so far based on this tutorial:
http://web.mit.edu/svn/src/swig-1.3.25/Examples/java/class/index.html is:

1.created a header Header.h with Visual Studio

```
class Test {
public:
    Test();
    ~Test();
    void showNumber();
private:
   int number;
};
```

2.created swig interface

```
/* File : Header.i */
%module Header

%{
#include "Header.h"
%}

/* Let's just grab the original header file here */
%include "Header.h"
```

3.In CMD run:

```
swig -c++ -java Header.i
```

4.Created SwigTest3.cpp

```
#include "Header.h"
#include <iostream>
Test::Test() {
    number = 12;
}
Test::~Test() {
}
void Test::showNumber() {
    std::cout << "Number: " << number << std::endl;
}
```

5.Created 64 dll from cpp & h files with Visual Studio

6.Created Java main.java class

```
public class main{
static{
    try {
    System.load("E:\\C++ projects\\SwigTest3\\SwigTest3\\SwigTest3.dll");
    } catch (UnsatisfiedLinkError e) {
    System.err.println("Native code library failed to load. See the chapter on Dynamic Linking Problems in the SWIG Java documentation for help.\n" + e);
    System.exit(1);
    }

}
public static void main(String argv[]){
        System.out.println("Hello");
        Test te = new Test();
    }
}
```

7.Running main.java gives me

```
Hello
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: HeaderJNI.new_Test()J
at HeaderJNI.new_Test(Native Method)
at Test.<init>(Test.java:38)
at main.main(main.java:13)
```

All the files are in the same folder. Please tell me what am I doing wrong.

Answer (score 1):

In step 3, swig creates a *_wrap.cxx file.

In step 5, you are only compiling the .cpp files, not the generated .cxx file.